# Angular check in html if a variable is undefined

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Here is book.isbn is sometimes undefined and if it is then I load a placeholder image.

```
src="http://covers.openlibrary.org/b/isbn/{{book.isbn[0]}}-L.jpg?default=false"
```

Comment: There are many ways to do that (1) use *ngIf="book.isbn != undefined" (2) you can call the function in src tag and check in the function

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for conditional source binding.

```
[src]="book.isbn ? pictureUrl : placeholderUrl"
```